# What does "<-" mean in a list comprehension?

Tags: string, haskell, variable-assignment, list-comprehension, operator-keyword

In this code:

```
[x | temp <- str, x <- isVowel temp]
```

I'm wondering what the

- `<-` operator does
- `<- str` operator does

`isVowel` returns true if its argument is a vowel.

Comment: Have you tried this code: does it compile, and what is the output?

Comment: the code works, I got help from friend doing this awhile back just want to try to actually do some learning. My thoughts r that <- is some sort of assignment, that str is a string with the list where X is the head and temp is the tail. 

What makes me confused is the , that kind of throws my thoughts off balance.

Comment: If `isVowel` has type `Char -> Bool`, then this code doesn't work. Anyway, have you tried googling "haskell list comprehension"? It turns up resources like [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing#List_comprehensions).

Comment: down votes without comments are not helpful folks

Comment: if "`isVowel` returns true if its argument is a vowel" then you should re-write it as `[x | temp <- str, x <- [isVowel temp]]`, or more conventionally as `[x | temp <- str, let x = isVowel temp]`. You read it out loud as "for each `temp` in `str`, ...".

Answer (score 6):

You're right that `<-` is sort of like an assignment.

For more information, [here's](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) an excellent resource for learning about list comprehensions.

> List comprehensions are very similar to set comprehensions. We'll stick to getting the first 10 even numbers for now. The list comprehension we could use is **[x*2 | x <- [1..10]]**. x is drawn from [1..10] and for every element in [1..10] (which we have bound to x), we get that element, only doubled.

However, that's not the whole story:

- `<-` is also used in [do notation](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#do-notation):

  > In a do expression, every line is a monadic value. To inspect its result, we use "<-".
- `<-` is even used in [monad comprehensions](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/237/) (although this isn't that helpful, since monad comprehensions are no longer in standard Haskell, I believe)

Answer (score 3):

In list comprehensions, `<-` is basically "foreach".  Every `pattern <- list` clause iterates over its `list`:  each successive element is extracted, and bound to the variable names in the `pattern` for the purposes of the remaining clauses, as well as the result expression.

So, it is very much like assignment.  The main conceptual difference from imperative languages is that there is no concept of modifying or updating variables:  the idea is that you are working with immutable values, which are newly "bound" to their name at every iteration.

Note that multiple `pattern <- list` clauses act like nested for loops.

Comment: I understand (and agree with) your saying that `<-` is like a `foreach`. Though, I'm a bit confused as to what happens when you use `<-` on something other than a list. For example, in the snippet given by the OP, we see `x <- isVowel temp`? What exactly goes on in such a situation? _NOTE: I'm also relatively new to Haskell..._ :)

Comment: @Miguel: It's a type error. In a list comprehension, the right hand side of `<-` must be a list.

Comment: @hammar Okay then. I thought that was weird. Thanks :)

Comment: main difference from `let`-binding is that `<-`-binding is not recursive, so shadowing is allowed, e.g. `[y | x <- list1, x <- g1 x, let y = g2 x]`. From the viewpoint of `g2`, it is as if `x` was mutated.

Answer (score 1):

You are better think of `<-` not as an operator but as a declaration.

`<-` resembles mathematical symbol `∈` ( `4 ∈ A` means the element 4 belongs to a set A) and has the same meaning in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely could be wrong, but I've always thought that `<-` reads as **in** so for

```
[x | temp <- str, x <- isVowel temp]
```

is like `temp` **in** `str` which could help you with your variable naming conventions.  So accounting for referential transparency it may read like ... *return a list of* `x` **in** `isVowel` **in** `str`.

Comment: "build a list of `x` **for** `x` **in** `isVowel temp` **for** `temp` **in** `str`". Or, in normal top-down order, "**for** `temp` **in** `str`, **for** `x` **in** `isVowel temp`, **collect** `x`".